# Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with an API that requires:

```
<trust level="Full" legacyCasModel="true"/>
```

to be set in my web.config file in order to work.   This works without a problem in VS 2010, but when I use VS 2013 I get an error stating that dynamic operations can only be performed in homogeneous AppDomain.   The project is targeting .NET framework 4.0 and is an asp.net MVC project.

I tried changing legacyCasModel to "false", but then I can't access the object I need. Not sure how to resolve this issue. How can I use legacyCasModel="true" in VS2013 with dynamic expressions?

Answer (score 2):

`legacyCasModel` forces a non-homogeneous domain as it is the pre-.net4 way of doing things. You can try to load it into a [different appdomain](http://www.bryancook.net/2010/02/running-code-in-separate-appdomain.html).

Comment: This makes sense, but seems like more trouble than it's worth.  Guess i'll stick with VS2010 for this project.